# Cassandra update max(a,b) function

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

How to make a request of this type in cassandra?

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_column1 = MAX(my_column1, 100) and my_column2 = my_column2 + 10;
```

max() function not exist. Can by using apache spark do this?
thanks!

Comment: Could I assume that the tag 'apache-spark' is because you want to use it for this purpose?

Comment: I use a Apache Spark to process data in Cassandra and I want to update the some records in a table  using the max logic function

Comment: Of course I can make a separate request to extract the necessary data and calculate the maximum in the Scala code and then update the entire record in Cassandra. However, if do so, the performance will be lower. I think maximum is very simple function that it was present in the update statement

Answer (score 2):

MAX is idempotent and seems like it is simple to do in this case the problem is that C* is a general database and needs to handle some edge cases. Particularly an issue is with deletes and TTLs, since as old data goes away it needs to still maintain the max.

A couple ways you can do this is either create a value that you update on inserts atomically or keep all the values inserted around in order so as things delete/ttl the old ones are still there to take its place (at the obvious disk cost).

```
 CREATE TABLE my_table_max (
     key text,
     max int static,
     deletableMax int,
     PRIMARY KEY (key, deletableMax) 
  ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (deletableMax DESC);
```

Then atomically update your max, or for the deletable implementation insert the new value:

```
  BEGIN BATCH
      INSERT INTO my_table_max (key, max) VALUES ('test', 1) IF NOT EXISTS;
      INSERT INTO my_table_max (key, deletableMax) VALUES ('test', 1);
  APPLY BATCH;

  BEGIN BATCH
      UPDATE my_table_max SET max = 5 WHERE key='test' IF max = 1;
      INSERT INTO my_table_max (key, deletableMax) VALUES ('test', 5);
  APPLY BATCH;
```

then just querying top 1 gives you the max:

```
 select * from my_table_max limit 1;

 key  | deletableMax | max
------+--------------+-----
 test |            5 |   5
```

Difference between these two would be seen after a delete:

```
delete from my_table_max WHERE key = 'test' and deletablemax = 5;
cqlsh:test_ks> select * from my_table_max limit 1;

 key  | deletablemax | max
------+--------------+-----
 test |            1 |   5
```

Since it keeps track of all the values in order the older value is kept;